# Appending an entry to an existing object (Relationships) : Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The main issue is with me trying to use the append function, and getting an SQL integrity error when I call session.commit(), even when the object is not being re-created. Here's my case:

I have a one to many relationship in a Flask SQLAlchemy database.
It's a Tag-Category relationship, tags belong to only one category, and by definition a category has many tags. For the sake of explanation, tags are being used on X objects.

In my Flask models file, I did this:

```
class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    category = db.Column(db.Text, unique = True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', backref = 'category', lazy = 'dynamic')

class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    tag = db.Column(db.Text, unique = True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
```

This should define a Category class to which I can "append" tags using the session.append(Tag) function.

Categories and tags are unique, I wanna take input from the user, and add the category/tag as the user specifies. In some cases, the user might want to just add a tag to an existing category.

The way I'm taking input is by using a form, from which I receive the category and tag, and I create the objects and add them to the database if they don't exist already, and if they do, I just want to append the tags to the X's or to the categories.

Here's my code:

```
category = Category(category = request.form['categories']) #Category related to its respective list of tags

tag_list = request.form.getlist('tags') # tags are received as a list

for tag_entity in tag_list:
    tag = Tag(tag = tag_entity)
    X.tags.append(tag)
    # Checking if the category exists or not in the database
    list1 = []
    if len(db.session.query(Category.tags).filter(Category.category == request.form['categories']).all()) != 0:
        list1 = db.session.query(Category.tags).filter(Category.category == request.form['categories']).all()
    list1.append(tag)
    for entry in list1:
        print entry.tag
    list1 = [entry.tag for entry in list1]
    # Here I should check if the tag already exists as well:
    db.session.add(tag)

# Only add category if it doesn't already exist
if len(db.session.query(Category.id).filter(Category.category == request.form['categories']).all()) == 0:
    print "I'm here"
    db.session.add(Category(category = request.form['categories'], tags = list1))
else:
    print "woops im here"
    newCat = Category(category=request.form['categories'])
    newCat.tags.extend(list1)
    db.session.merge(newCat)

db.session.add(X)
db.session.commit()
```

I know my code is really messy and it looks like it doesn't do what it's supposed to, that's a result of me just failing over and over again.

My main issue was with me trying to call category.tags.append(Tag), then getting an integrity error when session.commit() was being called even when the category was not even re-created.

I hope what I wrote makes sense, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of failing over and over, create an extremely simplified version, piece by piece, that should do what you're after and work from there. In other words produce a [mcve]. `tag = Tag(tag = tag_entity)` creates a new entity each time, and `db.session.add(tag)` will add that to the current session. Depending on your autoflush settings and data you'll get constraint violations sooner or later, because you've set `Tag.tag` to be unique. Also note that `db.session.merge(newCat)` doesn't do what you think, because `newCat` has no primary key set (so SQLAlchemy cannot find it), ...

Comment: ...and you discard the return value, which would be the merged or new entity. You should read the docs on [`Session.merge()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge).